# Jenkins console log out of order

Tags: python, jenkins

I wrote a python script in jenkins like this:

```
import subprocess, shlex

def command(cmd):
    return subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))

print '--- Begin ---'
command('ping -i 1 -c 3 192.168.1.2')
```

But the console log in jenkins is as follow:

```
PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_req=1 ttl=63 time=0.426 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_req=2 ttl=63 time=0.347 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.2: icmp_req=3 ttl=63 time=0.354 ms

--- 192.168.1.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.347/0.375/0.426/0.042 ms
--- Begin ---
```

Why does the PING's log show before `print '--- Begin ---'`?

Is it a jenkins bug? My jenkins version is v1.643

Comment: Should be caused by asynchronous subprocesses. It executes earlier than main program.

Comment: @knh170 I doesn't make sense because the log's order is normal if I run this script on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and fixed it by flushing `stdout`

In Python2

```
print "something" 
sys.stdout.flush()
```

In Python3:

```
print("something", flush=True)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a bug. If I don't remember badly, you can't open a child process in the jenkins shell (i.e the ping command will run independently from the python process). Thus, processes run asynchronously as @knh170 pointed.

Comment: If I wrap the python script into a file and call it from shell, the result is the same.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you wrap the script into another file. The issue is that you're calling a command (ping) which is external to your python program and therefore, python is not running it, so it runs in a different process (different pid).

When you run the script in your local machine, the processes are nested (ping process is a child of your python process). However, when you do so in Jenkins, processes are no nested but they run independently. Jenkins decides the order or even run them in parallel depending on its system configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that the subprocess is started asynchronously as @knh170 mentioned. So the output is printed right away, while Python is buffering the output until it's done.

You can try using:
`-u     Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered.`

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
```

or if you calling the script:

```
python -u <name>
```